# iText generated pdf hangs up browser tab

Tags: java, pdf, tabs, itext

### Description:

I'm using iText 2.1.7, for generate a simple pdf with an image and text to be opened in Internet Explorer (versions 10 and olders). The pdf is saved in a database in blob format.

### Problem:

When I click a button in a jsp to open it in a new tab, **it opens a new tab, a new window and the tab hangs** up like that:

[image: Frozen tab]

This is not suppose to happens, in any user workspace.

### Tests:

- Tried non adding an image, tab hangs up.
- Tried in I.E 7 of different pc (maybe different config) and doesn't happens
- Tried with non iText generated pdfs, doesn't happens.

### Supposition:

I suppose the pdf is malformed or something. It's happening just with iText generated pdfs;

### Code:

This is the method that generates the pdf:

```
public static void imageIntoPdf(byte[] file, 
OutputStream os, String  text)
        throws IOException, DocumentException {
    //os is a ByteArrayOutputStream
    Image image = null;
    try {
        image = Image.getInstance(file);
        Rectangle A4 = PageSize.A4;
        float scalePortrait = Math.min(A4.getWidth() / image.getWidth(),
                A4.getHeight() / image.getHeight());
        float w;
        float h;
        w = image.getWidth() * scalePortrait;
        h = image.getHeight() * scalePortrait;
        Document document = new Document(A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, os);
        Paragraph parrafo = new Paragraph(text);
        document.open();
        image.scaleAbsolute(w, h);
        float posH = (float) ((A4.getHeight() - h) / 2);
        float posW = (A4.getWidth() - w) / 2;
        image.setAbsolutePosition(posW, posH);
        image.setBorder(Image.NO_BORDER);
        image.setBorderWidth(0);
        document.newPage();
        document.add(image);
        document.add(parrafo);
        document.close();
    } catch (BadElementException bee) {
        throw new IOException(bee.toString());
    } 
}
```

And this is how I open it:

```
function openDoc(num){   
window.open("url/to_pdf&numDoc="+num,
'_blank','width=810,height=620,menubar=no,
toolbar=no,scrollable=yes,resizable=yes'); 
}
```

### Code tests:

Didn't found guide for my version, so tried with those guides:

- [Guide v5](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/zugferd-future-invoicing/2-creating-pdfa-files-itext). Couldn't even instantiate the class:

  PdfDocument pdfDocument = 
  new PdfDocument(new   PdfWriter(dest));
- [Guide v7](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-1). It is the most similar to my method, the difference is the outputStram. They use FileOutputStream, I used ByteArrayOutputStream. None of them make difference in the result. Same problem.
- Even being the same, in JavaScript tried with:

  function openDoc(num){
      var newTab = window.open("",'_blank');

  ```
  newTab.location("url/to_pdf&numDoc="+num,
  '_blank',
  'width=810,height=620,menubar=no,toolbar=no,
  scrollable=yes,resizable=yes'); 
      }
  ```

Comment: If you want to check whether a pdf document does not contain errors, there are two things you can do. First, you can use Adobe Reader and run a tool called "preflight". It checks whether the currently opened pdf adheres to the standard. Second, you can download and run the Pdf accessibility checker (PAC checker). It performs a similar (but stricter) check.

Comment: Have you tried to store the generated PDF into a file and open that one with a PDF reader/in the browser? How the `OutputStream` is handled outside the method?

Comment: @JorisSchellekens After a couple of hours searching around "preflight" I got it. It's a feature present only in Adobe Acrobat Pro versions. So I downloaded a trial, then I followed this: forums.adobe.com/thread/1489758 and got what I think I was looking for. The other one (PAC) couldn't even parse the pdf, and I didn't found instructions in its web. But I scanned another pdf that wasn't giving problems and neither accomplish pdf/a standard; like the iText pdf I've generated

Comment: @tomy instantiating a `PdfDocument` directly and using it like that (as you do in your sample code) is not how the class is to be used, use a regular `Document` there instead. Other than that the code you show should work assuming the image at `file` is ok. Unfortunately you font say what the `OutputStream os` is and whether sinned other code writes there, too.

Comment: @mkl Edited for more clarification. Pls avoid put possible answers in comments, because users use to write, leave and don't come back anymore.

Comment: it's not being a possible answer (and due to smart phone intelligent keyboards it's even partially unintelligible... sigh). That been said your edit didn't really clarify things, now it looks like you tried with different iText versions, sometimes trying 7.x style code with a 5.x or 2.x library, all somewhat chaotic. I would propose that you systematically address the issues. Start with your method `imageIntoPdf`, use it locally with a `FileOutputStream`. Does the result properly display in pdf viewers, in particular adobe reader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I forgot to set `response.setContentType(doc.getType());` as "application/pdf" in the servlet.
I had "image/png".